# Conflict between BeSimple Soap bundle and FOSRest Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, soap, fosrestbundle

I'm doing some *Rest* and some *SOAP* services, for the *REST* ones I'm using `FOSRestBundle` and for the *SOAP* type I'm using `BeSimple Soap Bundle` (this really is not that relevant as the problem is with a `FOSRest` listener *IMO*, but I say it just in case).

The thing is that the `FOSRest` offers a listener to handle the responses and serialize/render them like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * @Rest\View
 */
public function getAction()
{
  return $item;
}
```

And it handles the response serializing it into `JSON/XML` or whatever.
The conflict comes when I try to call my SOAP services and the listener yells at me saying that it does not support `SOAP` as a format (it supports JSON, XML, etc).

This happens when I put `view_response_listener: 'force'` into my FOSRest yml config file. If I change it to `view_response_listener: 'enabled'` the SOAP services do work but I seem to lose the so convenient FOSRest ability of autohandling my responses.

How could I achive that the `FOSRest view_response_listener` just handles the right responses letting the `SOAP Bundle` handle the soap type responses.

Edit:

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener: true
    format_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force' #This is the parameter that is driving me crazy. Value to 'force' Rest controllers work just fine SOAP don't, value to 'enabled' the other way around
        formats:
            xml: true
            json : true
        templating_formats:
            html: true
        force_redirects:
            html: true
        failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
        default_engine: twig
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
```

That is the `FOSRestBundle` configuration.

Here's my `routing.yml` for  both the *Rest* endpoints and the *SOAP* ones:

```
#config/routing.yml
rest_api:
  resource:    "@RESTBundle/Resources/config/api_routes.yml"
  host:        "%host_front%" #api.myproject.local
  type:        rest

#api_routes.yml detail
accounts:
    resource:    'RESTBundle\Controller\AccountsController'
    type:        rest
    name_prefix: api_

#config/routing.yml
soap_api:
  resource: "@SOAPBundle/Resources/config/soap_routing.yml"
  host:     "%host_ws%"
  prefix:   "%contexto_ws%"

#soap_routing.yml detail
_besimple_soap:
  resource: "@BeSimpleSoapBundle/Resources/config/routing/webservicecontroller.xml"
soap_ws:
  resource: "@SOAPBundle/Controller/"
  type: annotation
```

RestController example:

```
<?php

namespace RESTBundle\Controller\API;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation\ApiDoc as ApiDoc;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * @Rest\RouteResource("accounts", pluralize=false)
 */
class AccountsController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @Rest\View
     */
    public function getAction($userId)
    {
        return [
          ['name' => 'Example', 'pass'=> 'example'],
          ['name' => 'Example2', 'pass'=> 'example2']
        ];
    }
}
```

SOAP Controller:

```
/**
 * @Soap\Header("user", phpType="string")
 * @Soap\Header("token", phpType="string")
 */
class AccountsController implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    use ContainerAwareTrait;

    /**
     * @Soap\Method("getAccounts")
     * @Soap\Param("account", phpType="SOAPBundle\DataType\AccountFilter" )
     *
     * @Soap\Result(phpType="SOAPBundle\DataType\Account[]"")
     */
    public function getAccountsAction(Request $request, AccountFilter $filter)
    {
       return [(new Account())->setName('Example')->setPass('example')] //This is just an example
    }
}
```

Edit with the error:

> request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnsupportedMediaTypeHttpException:
>   "Format 'soap' not supported, handler must be implemented" at
>   /home/teampro/Sites/corinto/vendor/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/View/ViewHandler.php
>   line 292 {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnsupportedMediaTypeHttpException(code:
>   0): Format 'soap' not supported, handler must be implemented at
>   /.../vendor/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/View/ViewHandler.php:292)"}
>   []

Comment: Please update your question with `config`, it's quite hard to read through the lines :) Also, could you share your code?

Comment: @Samundra Done, it's not my code (can't post it here) but it's a dummy example based on it, so it yells the same stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define how make rules to listen like [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/configuration-reference.html) in the fos_rest config :

```
format_listener:
      rules:
        - { path: ^/, priorities: [ html, json, xml ], fallback_format: ~, prefer_extension: true } # default routes
        - { path: '/soap', priorities: [xml], fallback_format: xml, prefer_extension: true } # your soap route
        - { path: '^/rest', priorities: [xml, json], fallback_format: xml, prefer_extension: true } # your rest route
```

Hope this help !!

Comment: Have you got time to test ? I have made a same API on a server and this work well.

Answer (score 0):

first, explicity separate routing resources with `prefix` property

```
# app/config/routing.yml
_besimple_soap:
  resource: "@BeSimpleSoapBundle/Resources/config/routing/webservicecontroller.xml"
  prefix:   "%contexto_ws%"

rest_api:
  resource:    "@RESTBundle/Resources/config/api_routes.yml"
  host:        "%host_front%" #api.myproject.local
  prefix:      /rest
  type:        rest
```

For now it looks like that your REST controlller processes the WS route as it overlaps by configuraiton. Separating route namespaces with prefixes can help.

Second, verify the request host, as your configuration already splits the rouiting based on request host variable

Third, check the routing configuration with

```
bin/console debug:router
bin/console router:match
```

Comment: They're separated, the Rest ones have a prefix: 'api' (I just forgot to place it on the OP). Anyway, they've got their owm host as well. It's not about route colision, it's about the FOS listener trying to handle ALL the **responses**, even the ones that are SOAP.